# bad performance from too many caught errors?

Tags: c#, performance, error-handling

I have a large project in C# (.NET 2.0) which contains very large chunks of code generated by SubSonic. Is a try-catch like this causing a horrible performance hit?

```
    for (int x = 0; x < identifiers.Count; x++)
            {decimal target = 0;
                try
                {
                    target = Convert.ToDecimal(assets[x + identifiers.Count * 2]); // target %
                }
                catch { targetEmpty = true;  }}
```

What is happening is if the given field that is being passed in is not something that can be converted to a decimal it sets a flag which is then used further along in the record to determine something else.

The problem is that the application is literally throwing 10s of thousands of exceptions as I am parsing through 30k records.  The process as a whole takes almost 10 minutes for everything and my overall task is to improve that time some and this seemed like easy hanging fruit if its a bad design idea.

Any thoughts would be helpful (be kind, its been a miserable day)

thanks,
Chris

Comment: Try to read the following sentence and then replace each `Ouch!` instance with an exception and extrapolate the effect on your code: 
Yes, `Ouch!` there `Ouch!` could `Ouch!` be `Ouch!` a `Ouch!` small `Ouch!` perf `Ouch!` hit `Ouch!` from `Ouch!` all `Ouch!` these `Ouch!` exceptions.

Comment: I only started looking at this code recently... actually it looks like there are 3 similar tests testing if the 3 fields actually ARE decimals or if they are blank/null/non-decimal.  Then if all 3 flag fields are true it doesn't try to add the record.  Ugh... yeah, that is pretty sad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using exceptions for control flow is generally a bad practice (exactly because of the poor efficiency that you're observing). What type of data do you need to convert to `decimal`? Could you use `TryParse` method or some other method that doesn't throw exception if the input is not in the expected format?

[`Decimal.TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) should do the trick if you're parsing strings as it reports failure by returnning `false`:

```
decimal d;
if (Decimal.TryParse(str, out d)) 
  // Ok, use decimal 'd'
else 
  // Failed - do something else
```

Comment: many thanks, I replaced the 3 places where that particular horrid code was with the above and now the whole thing finished in LESS than 30 seconds!

Answer (score 5):

That is a truly horrible looking piece of code. In general exceptions should only be used to capture unexpected results. The fact that you are getting lots of exceptions means that this is a common condition that should become part of the intrinsic logic.

[decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) would be a far better option here and I would suggest caching the value of `identifiers.Count * 2` as well (not sure if compiler will optimise that)

Answer (score 3):

There's a [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) for Decimal as well. It avoids the exception and uses a bool instead to signal success/failure.

Answer (score 0):

It's scary looking code, and you're getting good suggestions on how to fix it.

If you want to know if those exceptions are costing you a big percentage of time, there's a simple way to find out.

Just pause it about 10 times, and each time examine the call stack. If the exceptions are costing some percentage of time like, say, 50%, then you will see it in the process of throwing or catching them on roughly that percent of pauses.